# How can I use wrapped Groovy shell inside the groovy script?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I have a Java app through which I'm executing a Groovy Script, the problem occurs when my Script again has code to use the groovy shell to execute the Inner script.

something like this

```
import com.xx.WrappedGroovyShell
import java.lang.*
 
def scriptString = """
def test(str) {
   str.toLowerCase() // This doesn't work as GString can't seem to be treated as a String
}
"""
 
try {
    
def script =  WrappedGroovyShell.getInstance().getScript("Test1", scriptString)
def script2 =  new GroovyShell().parse(scriptString) 

def example = 1
  def gstring = "OUR VALUE IS ${example}";
       println script instanceof GroovyObject // Statement returning false
       println script.test(gstring) // This throws an exception groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl.toLowerCase() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

       println script2 instanceof GroovyObject // Statement returns true
       println script2.test(gstring) //this one works
        

    println "Success"
} catch (ex) {
    println ex
}
 
return 0
```

The *getScript* method in WrappedGroovyShell.java is as simple as

```
public Script getScript(String scriptName, String scriptBody){
  return new GroovyShell().parse(scriptBody);
}
```

I will be thankful if someone let me know why two different behavior.

Comment: Why do you need a new groovy shell if you are inside one? The issue that you have 2 copies of groovy classes at the moment with 2 different class loaders...

Comment: As option you could pass current groovy classloader into constructor of groovyshell.

Comment: @daggett we have this requirement, the wrapped shell is supposed to cache the scripts for better utilization of memory. Why is it working for the second case?

Comment: to have better performance - better to minimize script parsing/compiling. so the simplest way - store compiled script in a map <ScriptSourceString, ParsedScript>. By creating new groovyshell you are not achieving the caching goal. the second case is working because it takes parent classloader from your groovy context and in first case from your java context. https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.java#L97

Comment: thanks, @daggett I did attempt to pass the class loader (Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()) to my wrapped shell then it's throwing the following, a small block of code would be really helpful.                                 
 exception,java.lang.ClassCastException: class Script1 cannot be cast to class groovy.lang.GroovyObject (Script1 is in unnamed module of loader groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader @71ec3ad0; groovy.lang.GroovyObject is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Answer (score 0):

`new GroovyShell()` creates a new groovy classloader with parent = `GroovyShell.class.getClassLoader()`

and if GString.class is unknown for parent classloader - then it will be loaded again.

two GString classes loaded by different classloaders are not equal that's why you could have unexpected exceptions like "method not found for parameter GString" or "can't cast GString to GString"

---

this code should work because it uses classloader of current groovy class

```
def scriptText='''
def test(str) {
   str.toLowerCase()
}
'''

def gs = new GroovyShell(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
def script = gs.parse(scriptText)

def arg = "GSTRING ${123}"
println script.test(arg)
```

Comment: Using GroovyShell to execute internal script works, what not working is the wrapped groovyshell, "WrappedGroovyShell.getInstance().getScript("Test1", scriptString)"

Comment: Pass to wrapped groovy shell the same classloader as you are using for current groovy

Comment: Not a java classloader but groovy